# Need to search string in all the column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 5 column in one table. I want to perform multifield search. It's possible...

```
Table - T
colmun  - TC1 , TC2 , TC3 , TC4 , TC5
```

Actual query

```
select *  from T 
where TC1='search' or TC2='search' or TC3='search' 
      or TC4='search' or TC5='search' or
```

Expected Query

```
select *  from T where <single condition > in ("searc")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CONTAINS predicate to query multiple columns by specifying a list of columns to search. The columns must be from the same table.

```
select * from T where CONTAINS( (TC1, TC2, TC3, TC4, TC5), 'search')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a CASE statement you only have to specify the `'search'` parameter once.

```
select *
from T
where case 'search'
        when TC1 then 1
        when TC2 then 1
        when TC3 then 1
        when TC4 then 1
        when TC5 then 1
        else 0
      end = 1
```